# First mass ceremony by a new priest

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the name for the first mass ceremony conducted by a new priest?

For example, in the catholic church, a priest for the first time transforms bread and wine into Eucharistia. After this mass, there is a celebration, feasting, people in the church welcoming the new priest.

Comment: How did you try to research this? Did you google for such info? Googling "*first mass by priest*" gives me the impression that there is no English word for this. It seems to be called a *priest's First Mass*, aka *Prima Missa neosacerdotum*.

Comment: This seems to be called a ***rite of induction***. I did not find a single word.

Comment: Thinking of an elected representative's first speech in a legislative chamber, I hope it's not (still?) called a ***virgin mass***. Too many connotations of virgin sacrifices for my blood!

Comment: @Drew In my first language (not English) we have a single word for that. As you noticed, searching did not yield a single word that is why I asked here.

Comment: I see. Is there a translation site you can go to, where you can type in that single word in your language and get a possible English translation? Have you tried Google translate? In any case, this site is not really about translation (to or from English), IMO. Sometimes you can get help with translation to English here, but that is not really what the site is about, IMO.

Comment: @Drew Even if I was not translating, the question as I posed it is of general interest and could be asked by a natural English speaker as well. Unfortunately google.translate (to my knowledge the most comprehensive online translator) does not recognize the word from my language and therefore does not provide the translation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Informally, this strikes me as an "inaugural mass".

However, you may infer from my last name that I may be less than qualified to opine in this area.